# Need help with problem of Invariance Principle

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This problem is from Arthur Engel's Problem Solving Strategies.

Problem:-

> Starting with a point S  (a,b) of the plane with 0 < b < a, we
> generate a sequence of points $(x_n, y_n)$ according to the rule
>
> $x_0 = a, y_0 = b, x_{n+1} = \frac {x_n + y_n}{2}, y_{n+1} =\frac{2x_ny_n}{x_n + y_n}$

Solution/Explanation:-

> Here it is easy to find an invariant. From $x_{n+1}y_{n+1} = x_ny_n$, for all n
> we deduce $x_ny_n = ab$ for all n. This is the invariant we are looking for. Initially, we have $y_0 < x_0$. This relation also remains invariant. Indeed, suppose $y_n < x_n$ for some n. Then $x_{n+1}$ is
> the midpoint of the segment with endpoints $y_n,x_n$. Moreover,
> $y_{n+1} < x_{n+1}$ since the harmonic mean is strictly less than the
> arithmetic mean. Thus,
>
> $0 < x_{n+1}−y_{n+1} =\frac{x_n−y_n}{x_n + y_n} ·\frac{x_n−y_n}{2} < \frac{x_n−y_n}{2}$ for all n.

Could anyone please help me understand how the paragraph concluded the equation in the end?

Comment: Please typeset your whole question in mathjax. it is not readable.

Comment: (I fixed it this time).

Comment: @YuvalPeres is it better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inductively, $x_n$ is decreasing and $y_n$ is increasing in $n$. Thus they both converge, and since the difference $x_n-y_n \to 0$, they have the same limit $L$. Since $x_n y_n=ab$ we get $L^2=ab$. In other words, iterating arithmetic and harmonic means converges to the geometric mean.
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Arithmetic-HarmonicMean.html

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Do you know how to accept an answer?

Comment: I did not. Just checked. Done :)